# ARIMA forecast keep getting error 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

Tags: r, arima

I keep getting an error when fitting my ARIMA to the data, 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'.

```
library(forecast)

foo <- read.csv("https://nofile.io/g/0qrJl41nhf3bQQFjBmM6JurzGJFQSioCTGEzZhWVl9zA1kXnAJsCsSsxN1ZN7F4D/data.csv/")

data <- data.frame(year, Car)
data <- ts(data[,2],start = c(1990,1),frequency = 1)

plot(data)
plot(diff(data),ylab='Differenced Car Usage')
plot(log10(data),ylab='Log (Car Usage)')
plot(diff(log10(data)),ylab='Differenced Log (Tractor Sales)')
par(mfrow = c(1,2))
acf(ts(diff(log10(data))),main='ACF Tractor Sales')
pacf(ts(diff(log10(data))),main='PACF Tractor Sales')

require(forecast)
ARIMAfit <- auto.arima(log10(data), approximation=FALSE,trace=FALSE)
summary(ARIMAfit)

par(mfrow = c(1,1))
pred <- predict(ARIMAfit, n.ahead = 3)
```

> Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
>     'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'

I'm simply not understanding what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate any help if anyone sees the issue.
Thanks
-MF

Comment: Where have you defined `Car`? I'm pointing to `data <- data.frame(year, Car)` line.

Comment: you haven't used `foo` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
library(forecast)
foo <- read.table(file="data.csv", header=T, sep=",")
data <- ts(foo$Car,start = c(1990,1),frequency = 1)

# Use 'forecast' to get predition from the model estimated by 'auto.arima'
ARIMAfit1 <- auto.arima(log10(data), approximation=T, trace=FALSE, allowdrift=F)
summary(ARIMAfit1)
forecast(ARIMAfit1, h = 3)

#      Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
# 2017       1.415713 1.165870 1.665556 1.0336109 1.797815
# 2018       1.415713 1.128307 1.703119 0.9761635 1.855262
# 2019       1.415713 1.095115 1.736310 0.9254014 1.906024


# The same model estimated using 'arima'
# Here you can use 'predict'
ARIMAfit2 <- arima(log10(data), order=c(0,1,1))
summary(ARIMAfit2)
predict(ARIMAfit2, n.ahead=3)

# $pred
# Time Series:
# Start = 2017 
# End = 2019 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 1.415713 1.415713 1.415713
# $se
# Time Series:
# Start = 2017 
# End = 2019 
# Frequency = 1 
# [1] 0.1911677 0.2199090 0.2453055
```

Comment: Could you please explain the parameters that you extensively set, the reason behind the error and how did it get resolved using those parameters?

Comment: It is more than a year and I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: Hi @InVinci. The reason behind the error is the use of `predict` for the object returned by `auto.arima`. The correct command is `forecast`. The `predict` command should be used for the model estimated by `arima`. The dataset used in my answer is only an example and is not relevant for the solution.

Comment: I am facing this issue even after using forecast. I never used predict.

Comment: @InVinci Please, open a new question on SO with a description of your problem.